# How can I divide/split up a matrix by rows between two other matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, split, row, partitioning

I have a matrix and a vector each with 3000 rows:

```
fe = [-0.1850   -0.4485; ...
      -0.2150    2.6302; ...
      -0.2081    1.5883; ...
      -0.6416   -1.1924; ...
      -0.1188    1.3429; ...
      -0.2326   -2.2737; ...
      -0.0799    1.4821; ...
      ... %# lots more rows
      ];

tar = [1; ...
       1; ...
       2; ...
       1; ...
       2; ...
       1; ...
       1; ...
      ...  %#lots more rows
      ];
```

I would like to divide up the rows of `fe` and `tar` such that 2/3 of them are placed into one set of variables and the remaining 1/3 are placed into a second set of variables. This is for classification purposes (i.e. one set is training data and the other is test data).

There are two potential ways for me to do this:

- Split up the rows in order, with the first 2/3 in one matrix and the last 1/3 in another.
- Randomly select and distribute 2/3 of the rows to one matrix and place the remainder in another.

How can I implement each of these solutions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you need to select 2/3 of the rows and both the columns, you can do

```
feTrain=fe(1:2000,:);
feTest=fe(2001:end,:);
```

If you wanted to assign 2/3 of the rows picked randomly (i.e., not the first 2/3), you can use the `randperm` function to generate random ordering of the row indices and use that to index.

```
nRows=size(fe,1);
randRows=randperm(nRows);%# generate random ordering of row indices
feTrain=fe(randRows(1:2000),:);%# index using random order
feTest=fe(randRows(2001:end),:);
```

Comment: Excuse me to plot feTrain How do you use Scatter, (feTrain has 2 columns)

Comment: `scatter` takes 2 vectors as inputs. So to plot 1st column vs 2nd column, do `scatter(feTrain(:,1),feTrain(:,2))`