# Random selection of matrix columns

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

I have an `m x n` matrix and I want to use it in some neural networks applications in MATLAB.

For example,

```
A = [ 24 22 35 40 30 ; 32 42 47 45 39 ; 14 1 10 5 9 ; 2 8 4 1 8] ;
```

I want to randomly train some columns and test the other remaining columns.
So, the first matrix will contain three random, distinct columns taken from the original matrix A, while the second matrix contains the remaining two columns.

How can I extract these matrices ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I divide/split up a matrix by rows between two other matrices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385174/how-can-i-divide-split-up-a-matrix-by-rows-between-two-other-matrices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do:

```
s = randperm(5); 
train = A(:, s(1:3));
test = A(:, s(4:end));
```

Answer (score 1):

Neural Network Toolbox comes with a set of functions that do this for you, such as `dividerand` and `divideblock`.